# R9 usage in iOS 2.x ABI?

Tags: ios, arm, abi

**What is the R9 register used for in the iOS ARM ABI?** In the ABI documentation it says that "*Register R9 has special usage*", without actually saying what it is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. `R9` is used as the current thread pointer.